# Micrometer @Timed for method in pojo not working

Tags: java, spring, micrometer

I am trying to instrument a method in a POJO class. When I use micrometer's @Timed annotation for a method in Spring controller class, it works fine and I can see metrics in prometheus dashboard(I have micrometer-registry-prometheus configured in pom). But when I use same annotation for a method in a POJO class(in same spring application) I don't see metrics in prometheus dashboard.

Do I need some extra config to get it working for a method in POJO class?

**Edit**: I have named metrics as

```
@Timed(value="myCustomMethod_responseTime")
```

Comment: You should check for your NamingConvention. Can you post your custom NamingConvention or post which one of the defaults are you using?

Comment: Edited the post with custom metrics.

Answer (score 4):

Controllers are instrumented automatically, you don't need `@Timed` on them.
Also, you need a few things to make this work:

- You need to create a `TimedAspect` `@Bean`
- The method you are instrumenting should be public and belong to a `@Bean`